# Why is the fail method being called from my jQuery.getJSON() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html page loaded directly from a local file in a web browser (FF 14.0.1 or Chromium, on Ubuntu 12.04)

The html page includes a local jQuery js file, and then includes a local js file with this method:

```
function start() {
     $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/app/connect?callback=?", "id=11", function() { alert("win!"); })
     .done(function() { alert("done"); })
     .fail(function(xhr, request, error) { alert(xhr.status + "<> + request + "<>" + error); }); }
```

I'm responding to these requests from a JBoss / Restful web server with no special configuration, the method on the server is annotated with @Produces({"application/json"}). Server doesn't show any errors, even gets the id value correctly.

When I trigger this javascript, the fail method is called and I get this alert:

```
200<>parsererror<>jQuery311391951_513134 was not called
```

I can see the JSON response when inspecting with Firebug, it looks ok. In Chromium, I can inspect the request / response headers and everything looks ok. I have that text saved, if anyone thinks it might give more insight.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Why do I get this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because you are expecting a jsonp response but you may not be sending a jsonp response from your server

Comment: You can remove the `callback=?` from the url

Comment: ah, i need to modify the response from the server! Thank you Arun. This request in the future might not be local, so i might still need the callback parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing a local resource, in that case you don't have to use jsonp. You can remove the `callback=?` from the url.

It is used if you have to access a third party resource with [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) violations

```
function start() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/app/connect", "id=11", function() { 
        alert("win!");
    }).done(function() { 
        alert("done"); 
    }).fail(function(xhr, request, error) { 
        alert(xhr.status + "<>" + request + "<>" + error); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  This request in the future might not be local, so i might still need the callback parameter?

Comment: then you will have to implement jsonp support in your serverside

Comment: @PhillipAtkinson a json response will be like `{ "name" : "some name"}`, but jsonp will be of format `<callback-passed-by-cliebt>({ "name" : "some name"})`

Comment: As a follow up, it works perfectly now. I added a servlet filter to wrap the json response in the callback (as found on another great answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350924/how-enable-jsonp-in-resteasy ). Thanks to everybody who helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are using JSONP (JSON with Padding). The server must unterstand the `?callback=` Paramater and wrap the JSON answer with the callback function. This is mandatory for calls where SOP restrictions apply. If not (same domain and port) then remove the callback parameter.